# Compiling Error "else without if "

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class ttttt
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a grade >> ");
        String grade = kb.nextLine();

        if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("High Distinction"))
        {
            System.out.println("Very well done");
        }
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("Pass");
        {
            System.out.println("well done");
        }
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("not pass");
        {
            System.out.println("need to work harder");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Questions are a good thing");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error "Else without if". What is the problem here? I have used semicolons correctly. Am I forgetting the syntax?

Comment: Indent your code and the error will pop up alone.

Comment: Please tag your posts with the language in question.

Answer (score 4):

`else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("Pass");` does not need `;` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket here:

```
 else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("not pass");
  {
     System.out.println("need to work harder");
  }
```

It looks like you are missing a few brackets.

Comment: The issue is the superfluous semicolons.